# Not able to see servers, process management menu's in the KIE workbench 6.2 wildfly distribution?

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor, kie

I have a less work experience with the drools and all. So I have gone through the KIE workbench 6.0 it's working fine, but I need the servers, process management menus in the version 6.2. After installation I am not able to see them, even installation didn't show any errors. Please suggest me how to get those things inside the KIE workbench version 6.2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tehre is no Drools 6.2 final (!) version out yet, so I wonder where you got this "distribution". Also, SO is not a good place for reporting bugs (if what you report is indeed a bug) in some PD software - you'd better use the Drools user list (on Google) for that or report an error on Drools JIRA site.

Comment: Thanks @laune for your quick response.I tried with the beta versions of the 6.2 distributions. Anyway thanks for your suggestions, I will follow the things you mentioned above. One more thing I would like to ask you regarding to the KIE workbench distribution 6.1. What my question is, Is there any possibility access KIE workbench (6.1) rules accessed using REST. If you know this information please give me idea regarding to those things. Because I tried with the REST API but it didn't provide much operations to fire rules and managing the rules. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation has a Chapter 13. Drools Camel Server, if that's the thing you want. Otherwise, start a new question, here and/or there.

Comment: Thanks @laune. I will follow as per the document. If any difficulty was occurred then I will raise the new question.

Comment: Hi @laune , I have gone through the document. But when I try to access the end point I am getting error like **Unable to connect**. Please tell me that am I miss anything related to the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually "servers, process manager" menus are there in kie workbench and not in drools workbench. drools download page has the drools workbench only. Please refer to http://salaboy.com/2013/10/22/kie-wb-jbpm-console-ng-configurations/ for some details in this context. You can download the kie-wb distributions from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/kie-wb-distribution-wars -- I myself was confused for a while till I figured it out.

Since this was one of the post found in google for this question I thought to post it here as an answer so that anybody else (and hopefully bhadhram too) can benefit from this info instead of investing another hour (like me) in searching the answer.